# VS 2022 17.8 Preview 1 - no longer serves Angular app

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, npm, visual-studio-2022

I just updated to 17.8 Preview 1, and now the Angular app doesn't start when I debug.  The API project still runs, and I can hit the API endpoints with Postman.  The browser launches to https://localhost:4200 but it doesn't reach out to the API because the Angular CLI didn't start it.  If I run `npm start` from the command line, then navigate to the same URL, the site loads as expected.

It seems like a bug was introduced with 17.8 Preview 1.  I tried a new project using the same template "Angular and ASP.NET Core (Preview)" and it won't run, either (right out of the box).  I'm hoping someone can either confirm it's a bug or explain what I need to do to get it working again.

I noticed that the .esproj files differ in a couple ways.

OLD:

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.89-alpha">`

NEW:

`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/0.5.105-alpha">`

`<ShouldRunBuildScript>false</ShouldRunBuildScript>`

Help!

Comment: Are you mixing a spa (angular) + ssr (asp) + rest api ( net core) ? :0  That kind of architecture at app level makes you prone to these errors. Angular should be in its own git repository far away of asp netcore backend. Each one on different servers

Comment: It's a project template that Microsoft introduced with VS 2022: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-angular?view=vs-2022.  It has 2 projects: an ASP.NET Core Web API project (server), and an Angular TypeScript project (client).  It's worked on every version of VS 2022 that I've installed until now.  It launches 2 console windows, one for each project.  This new version of VS 2022 only launches one console window for the Web API.  The other one it used to launch was the one that ran `npm start` (i.e., `ng serve ...`).

Comment: This is Preview 1 after all - there may be bugs and issues in it, report them to Microsoft to get fixed.

Comment: Angular works very well. The problem is when someone combine several technologies in one.

Comment: :) @JRichardsz - No one is saying anything bad about Angular.  This is an issue with a Preview version of Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: @PiersMyers - I already restored a backup, so I don't have that version of VS 2022 installed anymore.  Is there a way to report the bug to Microsoft without using VS 2022?

Comment: Visual  Studio is great for c#. If the problem continue, use any editor for angular.